# Get x509 Certificate In Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, x509, azure-cloud-services

I need to use a certificate for authentication with an Azure Key Vault, but I cannot access the key I have uploaded. I have taken these steps:

Uploaded key (.pfx) to Cloud Service via the portal.

Added this to ServiceConfiguration

```
<Certificates>
    <Certificate name="keyvault" thumbprint="<my_thumbprint>" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

Added this to ServiceDefinition

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="keyvault" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
</Certificates>
```

Using this code to retrieve key:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                <thumbprint_value>, false); // Don't validate certs, since the test root isn't installed.
    if (col == null || col.Count == 0)
                return null;
            return col[0];
}
finally
{
    store.Close();
}
```

However, when I start the service I see this exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: certificate
```

Is there any additional configuration I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're asking Fabric Controller to install the certificate in one location

```
<Certificate name="keyvault" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
```

while your code is reading the certificate from other location.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

Please make sure that you use same location in both places.

I would make the following change in `csdef` file:

```
<Certificate name="keyvault" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
```

And the following in the code:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Comment: Thanks. Using this configuration works locally, with the certificate installed using certmgr, but not when deployed to the cloud service.

Comment: This could be because you may already have the certificate installed in the store from where you're reading on your local machine. Please try running your code by removing the certificate from the "Personal" certificate store in "CurrentUser".

Comment: The problem that I was saving the certificate locally in a different store to the one it was saved in after being uploaded to Azure. To get this to work in Azure I need to create the x509 store like this: var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine). I can mark your answer as correct if you update those last two lines of code

Comment: That's correct. The location from where you're reading the certificate in code must match with what's defined in the csdef file.